# Symfony2 efficient displaying list of categories and related products

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got object `Category` and `Product` relation (one-to-many). I want to display list of all categories and objects related to them. If I use:

```
$categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeZebraBundle:Category')->findAll();
```

And than display this like that:

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
    <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
    <ul>
    {% for product in category.products %}
    <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It will generate additional query for each category.
I tried to add products to categories - instead of `findAll()` I used a method which retrieves all objects and add them to `ArrayCollection` of an appropriate category. But this does not reduce number of queries.

```
public function findAllLoadProducts()
{
    $categories = $this->findAll();
    $categortiesById = array();

    foreach ($categories  as $category)
    {
        $categortiesById[$category->getId()] = $category;
    }

    $products = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AcmeZebraBundle:Product')->findAll();

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        $categortiesById[$product->getCategory()->getId()]->getProducts()->add($product);
    }

    return $categortiesById;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hydrate the products to the categories in a custom query. Create a Repository for your Category entity in the same bundle (or use it if you already created it):

```
<?php
/* src/Acme/ZebraBundle/Repository/CategoryRepository.php */
namespace Acme\ZebraBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function retrieveHydratedCategories()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->select('c, p')
                    ->leftJoin('c.products', 'p')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();
    }
}
```

You can then use this query in place of your previous "findall":

```
$categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeZebraBundle:Category')->retrieveHydratedCategories();
```

The leftJoin makes the custom query fetch the products in the same query, avoiding any further query when you iterate on them in your template.

Comment: How to get only count of category products in that way without loading whole products collection for each category?